# ms access vba display all fields from a composite key in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, composite-key

I am looking for a way to display all fields involved in a composite key in a form field. This is to aid the users when they are entering multiple records to keep track of which they are working on. Currently, Access will only display on field from the Composite key.

On the form, I currently have a look up field to link to the HeaderData table. I want to take the value from that and find and display the associated record in a form field so users will know that they have entered the correct input and do not lose their place during data entry.

Here is what I tried, but I am showing no results:

```
Private Sub ProviderName_LostFocus()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim vcatch As String
  strSQL = "SELECT ID, AgencyID, ProviderName, AssessmentPeriod FROM HeaderData"
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("strSQL", dbOpenDynaset)

  If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
      If Me.ProviderName.Value = rs.Fields(ProviderName) Then
         vcatch = rs.Fields(ID) + " " + rs.Fields(AgencyID) + " " + rs.Fields(ProviderName) + " " + rs.Fields(AssessmentPeriod)
         Me.Text22 = vcatch
         rs.MoveLast
      Else
        rs.MoveNext
      End If
    Loop
    Me.Tally1.SetFocus
  End If

  rs.Close
  db.Close
End Sub
```

I have look all over an cannot find anything about displaying all fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes from the first argument to OpenRecordset:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Also, you need to surround the rs.fields() argument in quotes:

```
If Me.ProviderName.Value = rs.Fields("ProviderName") Then
```

Finally, I would not change the state of the CurrentDb. You found it open, leave it open.
(remove second to last line)

---

So, cleaning this up a bit:

```
Private Sub ProviderName_LostFocus()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim vcatch As String
strSQL = "SELECT ID, AgencyID, ProviderName, AssessmentPeriod FROM HeaderData"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
   rs.MoveFirst
   Do While Not rs.EOF
     If Me.ProviderName.Value = rs.Fields("ProviderName") Then
       vcatch = rs.Fields(ID) + " " + rs.Fields(AgencyID) + " " + rs.Fields(ProviderName) + " " + rs.Fields(AssessmentPeriod)
       Me.Text22 = vcatch
       Exit Do
     Else
       rs.MoveNext
     End If
   Loop
   rs.close
   Me.Tally1.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. IT seems to be catching the correct information, but it is giving me the error: Runtime error 13: Type mismatch on the "vcatch = ..." line. Not sure why this issue is coming up. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please ignore the last Comment. All I had to do was change the "+" signs to "&" signs. This cleared the mismatch error.

Comment: The concatenation operator in VBA is "&", not "+", as you have discovered.